# SynTPEnh.exe constantly restarting/respawning in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, drivers, synaptics-touchpad

I just upgraded to Windows 10 and I noticed that the `SynTPEnh.exe` process is constantly restarting/respawning

To be more precise, there are two `SynTPEnh.exe` processes. One of them (with pid 2972 in the below pictures) is always there.

[image]

However, every ~5 seconds a second `SynTPEnh.exe` process pops up (pid 16192 in the below picture) then disappears in about a second.

[image]

I know that these processes belong to the Synaptics trackpad and I have downloaded the latest driver for Windows 10 on their website ([`Windows 10 PS/2 and SMBus Devices v19.0.19.1`](http://www.synaptics.com/en/drivers.php)) but the problem is still there.

Is anyone having the same issue and know if there's a fix for this?

Answer (score 1):

Removing the service at start is **not** a good idea because this service does provide functionality for synaptic touchpads. Without this service mouse pointer can behave erratically and jump over the screen.

I successfully resolved the issue. In this case I looked into event viewer and saw the error 7011. This means the service took too long to start after login and timeout occured after 30000 milliseconds. Manually starting the service did work though.

So I increased the timeout limit to 120000 milliseconds (2 Minutes) and the service could start after login (it took a while, acutually longer than 30 seconds, after the service was running).

1. To increase the timout limit open regedit.exe and go to key
   `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control`
2. Then make a new DWORD (32-Bit) and name it  `ServicesPipeTimeout`
3. Change the value to decimal 120000 and reboot.

Source 1: [Kepware Knowledge Base: Solution](https://www.kepware.com/en-us/support/knowledge-base/2011/increasing-the-timeout-on-startup-services)

Source 2: [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51495822/is-there-a-way-to-increase-windows-service-startup-timeout-for-a-specific-servic)

Answer (score 0):

I have this issue and just got to understadning and solution.

The problem is matter of two conflicting SynTPEnh.exe processes. It is essentially the same process launched twice by mistake.

One (stable) is launched from the "Run" registry key, second (restarting) is launched by a service "SynTPEnh Caller Service".

**SOLUTION:** remove SynTPEnh.exe from the "Run" registry key (with msconfig for example)

Comment: which registry key is that?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376977.aspx

Either HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run or
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run I suppose.

You can just use windows' "msconfig" util.

Comment: I was confident I was having the same issue on my ThinkPad, but there were no Synaptics HKLM/HKCU Run registry or task scheduler entries present. The continuous restarting of a second SynTPEnh.exe instance was causing CPU spikes (therewith affecting performance and draining battery), so I decided to reinstall the driver which resolved the issue completely. Remember to get the driver directly from your manufacturer (ie Lenovo) – not Synaptics!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, namely, the SynTPEnhService process was constantly restarting and causing CPU spikes.

[image: Windows Event Viewer with lots of SynTPEnhService errors]

I solved it by installing the latest version of the driver from the [Lenovo website](https://support.lenovo.com/ru/th/downloads/ds103454). Note my PC isn't a Lenovo, it's an HP, but it still solved the issue.

I had to restart my computer after installing the driver for the fix to take effect.

Here's a [related discussion](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Enterprise-Client-Management/T440-X240-Synaptics-touchpad-driver-software-causing-excessive-application-event-log-entries/m-p/4463060?page=1#4463822) on the Lenovo forums.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem [after installing Synaptics precision drivers over my Synaptics drivers](https://superuser.com/a/1768171/549571). Reinstalling the driver several times did not help and a timeout wasn't the problem either.

However, [you can turn off synaptics enhancements [...] (Precision Touchpad enabled models only)](https://www.reddit.com/r/spectrex360/comments/gsjz44/psa_2_you_can_turn_off_synaptics_enhancements_for/) without any problems and even save energy/battery life as follows:

- Press the Windows Key + R button to open the Run box
- Type **MSConfig** and press Enter
- In the *MSConfig* window, select the *Services* tab
- Uncheck the box for *SynTPenh Caller Service* and click *ok*
- Restart