# How to install Windows precision touchpad driver for a HP Spectre x360 (early 2018 model)

Tags: windows, windows-11, touchpad, synaptics-touchpad, hp

How can I install a precision touchpad driver for a HP Spectre x360 Convertible 13-ae002ng (product no. 2QG13EA#ABD) laptop from early 2018 in Windows 11?

The problem is that the Synaptics drivers provided by HP and Windows are no precision drivers. Only for the later models from 2018 precision drivers have been included.

There was even the [Demand Precision Touchpads on the HP Spectre x360](https://www.thepetitionsite.com/de/279/075/190/stand-up-to-hp-and-demand-precision-touchpads-on-the-spectre-x360/) petition about it.

Comment: Try this HP Site    ....    https://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/laptops     You need your serial number to access

Comment: Your driver page>>>>>>https://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/selfservice/hp-spectre-13-ae000-x360-convertible-pc/16779579

Comment: The problem is that the Synaptics drivers provided by HP and Windows are no precision drivers. I added this to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Note: The following solution is probably not limited to HP laptops. See comment from Envy laptop user. More comments welcome!**

In 2017 Windows 10 installation instructions appeared at [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/6qz30h/enable_precision_touchpad_on_hp_spectre_x360_2017/) (referenced at [The Verge](https://www.theverge.com/2017/8/20/16175682/enable-precision-drivers-on-synaptics-touchpads), [superuser](https://superuser.com/a/1242730/549571), [Windows Central](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-enable-precision-touchpad-drivers) and [How-To Geek](https://www.howtogeek.com/325347/how-to-enable-microsofts-precision-touchpad-drivers-on-your-laptop/)) using the Lenovo driver [n1mgx14w.zip](https://download.lenovo.com/pccbbs/mobiles/n1mgx14w.zip). This solution didn't seem to be limited to HP laptops. In 2019 problems with the Synaptics driver update version 19.5.10.75 and how to avoid it were discussed at [HP Community](https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Hardware-and-Upgrade-Questions/Precision-Touchpad-Driver/m-p/6971887/highlight/true#M494520). Unfortunately all solutions stopped working after the Synaptics driver version 19.5.x was included in the Windows feature update version 2004 in May 2020 because it could not be *rolled back* through the Device Manager driver update as usual as reported at [HP Community](https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Hardware-and-Upgrade-Questions/Windows-10-update-2004-as-of-July-2020-breaks-touchpad-of-HP/m-p/7681290/highlight/true#M582969). Also a registry entry could not block the driver update.

However this new instructions at [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/spectrex360/comments/jfan8e/finally_got_the_precision_touchpad_working_hp/) explains how it is still possible getting the Lenovo precision drivers working with all later Windows 10 updates including Windows 11. I encountered a new problem and describe here, how it can be avoided. One option is using the newer precision driver [n1mgx28w](https://download.lenovo.com/pccbbs/mobiles/n1mgx28w.exe) as described at [HP Community](https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Operating-System-and-Recovery/Original-touchpad-drivers/td-p/6798624). This also provides *edge region filtering* which previously was greyed out and possibly some other improvements. I also tried the even newer driver *n1mgx39w*, but it didn't work. The installation process is as follows:

***IMPORTANT: Its is a very fragile process and you need to follow it precisely!!!***

**1. Download Synaptics TouchPad drivers**

You will need either 1, 2 (recommended) or 1, 3, 4 (not recommended).

1. HP version 19.3.31.31 Rev.B (Windows 10 v1803): [sp87984.exe](https://ftp.hp.com/pub/softpaq/sp87501-88000/sp87984.exe)
2. Lenovo precision driver version 19.3.4.111 [n1mgx28w.exe](https://download.lenovo.com/pccbbs/mobiles/n1mgx28w.exe)
3. Lenovo precision driver version 19.3.4.58: [n1mgx14w.zip](https://download.lenovo.com/pccbbs/mobiles/n1mgx14w.zip)
4. HP version 19.5.10.75 Rev.C (Windows 10 v1803): [sp92533.exe](https://ftp.hp.com/pub/softpaq/sp92501-93000/sp92533.exe)

**2. Set Laptop to *Flight mode***

> **3. Rolling back to the barebones PS/2 touchpad driver**
>
> - Keep uninstalling the touchpad with the checkbox on for uninstalling all previous drivers until you only have ONE touchpad device (not PS/2 touchpad driver + HID device or Synaptics driver + HID or Synaptics by itself, has to be PS/2 driver and driver only. Don't worry if the PS/2 driver self updates to the 2019 driver by itself automatically if you accidentally installed the optional driver through Windows Update like I did, you just have to get it to this point where a mouse is visible and PS/2 driver is what is showing on the Device Manager which can take a few restarts)

The *Device Manager* should look like this:

[image: Device Manager 1]

and touchpad settings without precision touchpad options.

[image: No precision touchpad options]

> **4. Install the 19.3.x Synaptics driver over the PS/2 driver.**
>
> This will be your base, restart. Make sure your 19.3.x Synaptics driver is working, verify it's on version 19.3.x one through Device Manager.

Note: The touchpad needs to be installed as **Synaptics SMBus ClickPad** in Device Manager and no other HID device may show up. Otherwise start over again. The easiest way to accomplish this is running **Setup.exe** of the Synaptics driver 19.3.x. Alternatively you can use *Update* of device manager. Then you need to select **Synaptics SMBus ClickPad** after the *Have Disk* dialog. If it says device not recognized, role back the driver, restart and try again. Likewise if ***Setup.exe*** fails, restart and try again. It usually works the second time.

The *Device Manager* should now look like

[image: Synaptics SMBus ClickPad]

with Synaptics driver version 19.3.31.31.

[image: Synaptics driver version 19.3.31.31]

> **5. Installing Precision drivers**
>
> - Once you have a working driver base, install the Lenovo *n1mgx28w* or *n1mgx14w* Precision Touchpad driver over it. Restart and make sure a cursor shows and works. Do this following the above instructions at [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/6qz30h/enable_precision_touchpad_on_hp_spectre_x360_2017/) or [The Verge](https://www.theverge.com/2017/8/20/16175682/enable-precision-drivers-on-synaptics-touchpads).

> - Go to devices manager, right click on the touchpad devices
> - Click "Browse my computer for driver software https://i.stack.imgur.com/OSn6s.png
> - Let me pick from a list of available drivers on my computer https://i.stack.imgur.com/KiPtw.png
> - Click "Have Disk" https://i.stack.imgur.com/PfAh1.png
> - Then browse the autorun.inf in your driver folder https://i.stack.imgur.com/9sc9O.png
> - Choose the Synaptics Pointing Device and click Next https://i.stack.imgur.com/tewQS.png
> - Finishing the driver installation
> - Reboot and enjoy the Precision touchpad.
>
> Here is the video tutorial from Windows Central: https://youtu.be/5MRpAsAhsvY

Finally the *Device Manager* should look like

[image: Final result with n1mgx14w]

with Synaptics driver version 19.3.4.111 or 19.3.4.58

[image: Synaptics driver version 19.3.4.58]

and touchpad settings with precision touchpad options.

[image: Precision touchpad options]

**6. Block version 19.5.x of the Synaptics driver update**

You can block the driver update with **wushowhide.diagcab** (unreliable) or with the following registry entries (reliable):

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\DeviceInstall\Restrictions]
"DenyDeviceIDs"=dword:00000001
"DenyDeviceIDsRetroactive"=dword:00000000

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\DeviceInstall\Restrictions\DenyDeviceIDs]
"1"="ACPI\\VEN_SYN&DEV_326A"
"2"="ACPI\\SYN326A"
"3"="*SYN326A"
```

Save it as **DeviceInstall+Restrictions.reg** and replaced the 3 keys by your *Hardware ID*. You can find it in the *Device* tab of the touchpad properties of *Device Manager*.

**7. Leave *Flight mode***

**8. Test *Windows update***

Its a good idea to run a Windows update now, to check if version 19.5.x of the Synaptics driver update gets accidentally installed. If this is the case immediately *roll back* the driver through Device Manager before a restart (otherwise its too late and you need to start all over again). Try to block the update again until it doesn't get installed. Then this update should not happen again until a bigger Windows update.

**If you used n1mgx28w (v19.3.4.111) the following problems don't occur and you are finished.**

If you used n1mgx14w (v19.3.4.58) a remaining new problem was [SynTPEnh.exe constantly restarting](https://superuser.com/q/1032881/549571). What's worse, more SynTPEnh instances get started then killed and accumulate over time to a heavy load. Reinstalling the driver as suggested - even several times - did not help and a timeout wasn't the problem either. However, the problem disappeared after reverting an accidental 19.5.35.47 driver update of Windows 11. So it turned out, that the solution is replacing the Synaptics **SynTPEnhService.exe** in the driver directory with its 19.5.x version. To

**9. replace *SynTPEnhService.exe with its 19.5.x version***

- run in *PowerShell* as administrator:

`Stop-Service "SynTPEnhService"; kill -name SynTPEnh; kill -name SynTPHelper"`

- extract the 19.5.10.75 Rev.C driver directory from [sp92533.exe](https://ftp.hp.com/pub/softpaq/sp92501-93000/sp92533.exe)
- copy **SynTPEnhService.exe** to the installation directory, in my case **C:\Program Files\Synaptics\SynTP\**

`Start-Service "SynTPEnhService"`

The first start of this service takes much longer, so it seem like something is getting repaired. Thereafter SynTPEnhService.exe can be replaced again by its former version 19.3.4.58 or even 19.3.31.31. Same holds for the other two Synaptics enhancements files SynTPEnh.exe and SynTPHelper.exe. Their newer version might be better but I haven't noticed any other difference so far.

Alternatively [you can turn off Synaptics enhancements [...] (Precision Touchpad enabled models only)](https://www.reddit.com/r/spectrex360/comments/gsjz44/psa_2_you_can_turn_off_synaptics_enhancements_for/) and even save energy/battery life by disabling *SynTPEnh Caller Service* through the *Service* tab of *MSConfig* ([detailed instructions](https://www.thepcsolver.com/syntpenh-exe/)). However, in this case the precision touch stops working after resuming Windows from *sleep*. Maybe the solution at [superuser](https://superuser.com/a/1242730/549571) could solve the problem, but I didn't try. However, if you disable the *SynTPEnh Caller Service* there will be no scroll icon and following step is not necessary.

The Synaptics enhancements show an icon at the mouse pointer when scrolling. This can be difficult to work with because it is hiding the pointer area. To

> **10. Remove the scroll icon**
>
> - Type in RegEdit in your Start menu. Go to
> - 'Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Synaptics\SynTPEnh' [...]
> - create a New DWORD (32-bit) value
> - Name the value 'UseScrollCursor' and make sure the value is set to '0'

or save and run this registry entry e.g. as **Synaptics+UseScrollCursor.reg**

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Synaptics\SynTPEnh]
"UseScrollCursor"=dword:00000000
```

> - restart

Comment: This comment was suggested by an anonymous user as an edit. So I post it here as a comment: 
_Note from experience: I installed the Lenevo drivers on my HP Envy. (I didn't bother with any of the 'flight' mode instructions below). They stopped my trackpad from working completely, so I 'rolled back' drivers and - far from rolling back to what I had before (no two-finger scroll option) - I got a fully functional trackpad with all options. No idea why this worked, but it sort of did._